# Implementing secure E voting Foo Scheme

Tags: php, phpseclib, voting-system, electronic-signature

I'm working on electronic voting system(Foo Scheme) in php. for rsa encryption I have used phpseclib. but I don't know how to blind and unblind message. For more information I have put a document [Here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220369818_Data_Anonymity_in_the_FOO_Voting_Scheme/file/32bfe5103f811ee8a1.pdf). I really can't understand the explaination of page 8 and 9. If you have worked on Electronic voting please help me!

Comment: The website you linked to seems a bit picky in the emails it accepts. In lieu of having seen the document I think http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ might be better suited for your question idk.

Comment: Thank you buddy, but It was mathematically proofs and phpseclib is not mathematically enough.

Comment: Question - why not use a service that just handles the entire security and recording for you like DocuSign?  Check out www.docusign.com/devcenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been reading about blind signatures on wikipedia and...

phpseclib already does blinding to an extent when it's doing it's modular exponentiation. Both RSA blinding and blind signatures require the random value to be relatively prime to the modulo. phpseclib uses a the chinese remainder theorem to do the exponentiation on p and q instead of N and to sorta combine them and since p and q are prime anything less than p or q is trivially easily relatively prime to them.

Unfortunately, this technique doesn't work for blind signatures since, with those, the person doing the initial blinding would only have access to the public key.

Anyway give me a few days and I'll try to whip something up as time permits.